# regex function that eliminates comments in a string

Tags: python, whitespace

*Complete the solution so that it strips all text that follows any of a set of comment markers passed in. Any whitespace at the end of the line should also be stripped out.
Example:
Given an input string of:*

```
apples, pears # and bananas
grapes
bananas !apples
```

The output expected would be:

```
apples, pears
grapes
bananas
```

**My Function:**

```py
    import regex
    
    def solution(string,markers):
    
        i = regex.sub('{}.*|\s*{}.*'.format(*markers),'',string)
    
        return i
```

**1) `solution("apples, pears # and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples", ["#", "!"])`**

*Ideal Result:*
"apples, pears\ngrapes\nbananas"

*Actual Result:*
'apples, pears \ngrapes\nbananas' **Error: There's a space after 'pears'**

**2) `solution("a #b\nc\nd $e f g", ["#", "$"])`**

*Ideal Result:*
"'a\nc\nd"

*Actual Result:*
'a \nc\nd $e f g'  **Error: There's a space after 'a' and '(space)$e f g' shouldn't be there**

Comment: Do you have to use regex?

Comment: Not really. Seemed regex would be better but any other methods are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solution:

1. use simple `re`. It has all you need in this case,
2. You dont need `(whatever)|\s*(whatever)`. The first alternative is redundant,
3. Use `(marker1|marker2|...|markern)` for comment markers formed by `"|".join*()`. Why not character class? Because a comment marker can consist of more than one character, i.e. `//`,
4. Escape comment markers for regex with `re.escape()`,
5. Use `$` assertion with `re.M` flag to reach the end of the comment string.

Python 3:

```py
import re
def solution(string: str, markers: list) -> str:
    return re.sub('\s*(' + '|'.join(map(lambda str: re.escape(str), markers)) + ').*$', '', string, 0, re.M)

# Test:
print (solution('apples, pears # and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples', ['#', '!']))
print (solution('a #b\nc\nd $e f g', ['#', '$']))
```